# how to sum doubled value and another value in MIPS?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm new to assembly language and I have a task I couldn't solve. the question is (Write a program to ask the user to enter two integers A and B and then display the result of
computing the expression: A + 2B - 5.), I've tried to make the user enter a value then make him enter another value, but the result will be doubled, now I want to sum these two values with the constant number using (addiu) but the thing is when I do assembly then run, I insert the values required then it gives me random numbers! I couldn't find what was wrong with my code. please help

my code :

```
.data 
str1: .asciiz "enter A value: "
str2: .asciiz "enter B value:"
str3: .asciiz "A+2B-5="

.globl main
.text
main:
  li $v0,4 
  la $a0,str1 
  syscall  

  li $v0,5 
  syscall 
  move $t0,$v0   

  li $v0,4 
  la $a0,str2 
  syscall  

  li $v0,5 
  syscall

  move $t1,$v0 
  add $t1,$t1,$t1  
  move $t1,$v0 

  syscall  

  add $t2,$t1,$t0
  move $t2,$v0 

  syscall

  li $v0,4 
  la $a0,str3 
  syscall

  addi $t3,$t2,-5
  syscall

  li $v0,1 
  syscall
```

Comment: A `syscall` generally requires a sequence of instructions.  A syscall without the appropriate sequence, means the system won't understand what you're trying to do.  Have a look at the edited code to see the syscalls that aren't associated with a proper sequence.

Comment: Otherwise, use single step in the debugger.  Debugging assembly is similar to debugging other code: step each line and verify program state in between each line.  Since most instructions are very simple, usually this verification means checking that the updated register has the value you expect.  Do this for every instruction.

Comment: same thing, i got these random numbers again. thank you

Comment: If you had single stepped with the debugger and verified program state, you would have seen some bad program state at several places in that code.  If you don't find and the bad program states and address the causes, you'll get the same results.

Comment: Thank u so much, finally, I got it and solved the problem

Comment: @RawanAljanabi consider posting a [self answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) that describes what the issue was and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

apparently I was saving the values that the user entered in the wrong register
I fixed that and that's the right written code :

```
.data
str1: .asciiz "enter A value: "
str2: .asciiz "enter B value:"
str3: .asciiz "A+2B-5="

.globl main
.text

main:
 li $v0,4 
  la $a0,str1  
  syscall
   
  li $v0,5  
  syscall 

  move $s0,$v0 

  li $v0,4 
  la $a0,str2 
  syscall

   li $v0,5 
  syscall 
  move $s1,$v0 

  add $s1,$s1,$s1 
  move $a0,$s1 
  
   add $s2,$s0,$s1 
  move $a0,$s2 #

  li $v0,4 
  la $a0,str3  
 syscall
  
  subi $s3,$s2,5 
   li $v0,1 
  move $a0,$s3
  syscall
```

Comment: When adding code into a post, please surround it in three backticks (\`\`\`) to format it as code. You can find more info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: `move $s1,$v0` / `add $s1,$s1,$s1` can just be `add $s1, $v0,$v0`.  Or `slli $s1, $v0, 1`.  MIPS is a 3-operand ISA where the destination doesn't have to be one of the sources.  You also don't need to be using call-preserved (`$s`) registers, you can be using temporary `$t0..9` registers especially between system calls, but MARS system calls only modify `$v0` (and sometimes memory for input).